# How can I report all hits from a repeat characters?

Tags: python

Here is the string I get: `aaaaaa`, And I want to report all the positions of pattern: `aaa`.

```py
>>> for m in re.finditer('aaa', 'aaaaaa'):
...     print(m.start())
...
0
3
```

But I want to report the starts of all the hits:

```
0
1
2
3
```

Comment: [`(?=(aaa))`](https://regex101.com/r/MjGtDC/2)

Comment: You could just run the match over substrings

Comment: @MateenUlhaq, thanks, `Substring` is a solution, I want to known how can I finish using `regex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) expression and transform your pattern into [`(?=(aaa))`](https://regex101.com/r/MjGtDC/3):

```
for m in re.finditer('(?=(aaa))', 'aaaaaa'):
    print(m.start())
```

To get match text you need to use `m.group(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
x = 'aaaaaa'
for i,_ in enumerate(x):
    if x[i:].startswith('aaa'):
        print(i)
```

Comment: Thanks, It is a solution, any way. I wonder how can I use the `pattern` to search using `re` module.